# How to load the result of a php function into a variable

Tags: php, function

I have a php file on my server that takes in two inputs through the URL and then comes back with a result. When a page is loaded, I'd like to have the result of that calculation already loaded. For example:

```
$var = load("http://mysite.com/myfile.php?&var1=var1&var2=var2");
```

I know that load isn't a real function for this, but is there something simple that suits what I'm looking for? thanks

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents  But why would you do a full-blown http request to talk to a "local" script? It'd be far simpler to turn this script into a function you can load via `include()` and invoke s needed.

Comment: thanks, I may indeed do that now that you mention it. I am a rookie at PHP ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$foo = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/myfile.php?&var1=var1&var2=var2');
```

Or, a better solution if the file is located on your server:

```
include('myfile.php');
```

and either set the `$_GET` variables in the included script itself, or prior to including it.

Answer (score 0):

If they are running on the same server, consider calling the script directly?

```
$_GET["var1"] = "var1";
$_GET["var2"] = "var2";
include "myfile.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), but it may be a more practical solution to simply include the file and call the function directly in the file, rather than trying to manually load the file.